# Differential expression for mass-out of a control volume

Tags: fluid-dynamics, mass, conservation-laws, differentiation, differential-equations

I am trying to express the rate of change of mass with respect to time out of a control volume. My control volume has dimensions $dV = dx\,dy\,dz$. For the mass-in change with respect to time I evaluated it as follows:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial m_{in}}{\partial t} &= \frac{\partial m_{in,x}}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial m_{in,y}}{\partial t} +\frac{\partial m_{in,z}}{\partial t}\\
&= \rho A_{yz} \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + \rho A_{xz}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t} + \rho A_{xy}\frac{\partial z}{\partial t} \\
&= \rho A_{yz}u + \rho A_{xz}v + \rho A_{xy}w \end{align}
My understanding here is that $\rho$ is assumed to be constant, along with the surface area through which the mass flows in, and areas are: $A_{xy} = dx\cdot dy$, similarly for the other sub-indices (yz and zx).

I start getting confused trying to do the same "derivative" expansion for the mass-out:

$$\frac{\partial m_{out}}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial m_{out,x}}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial m_{out,y}}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial m_{out,z}}{\partial t}$$

In the x-direction:

$$\frac{\partial m_{out,x}}{\partial t} = \rho \frac{\partial V_{out}}{\partial t}$$

I know I am supposed to arrive to the following: $ \frac{\partial m_{out,x}}{\partial t} = \rho u(x+dx)A_{yx}$, but I am really struggling to get there; how can I explicitly get to that result by taking the derivative of the volume at the way out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, draw a picture.

[image]
([source](https://www.tec-science.com/mechanics/gases-and-liquids/derivation-of-the-continuity-equation-conservation-of-mass/))

At the green boundary, the flux (mass density transfer rate) through the surface $A_x=\Delta y\Delta z$ is,
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}m_{x,\text{in}}}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\Delta V_{x,\text{in}}\rho\right)=\rho\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\Delta A_x\cdot\mathrm{d}x_\text{in}\right)=\rho\Delta A_x\frac{\mathrm{d}x_\text{in}}{\mathrm{d}t}=\rho\Delta A \,u_\text{in}$$
where we used the fact that the density is constant in the volume.

The *same* analysis can be done at the red boundary, but since the velocity is now the *outflux* (rather than the influx), then we must replace all of the uses of the 'in' subscript with 'out' and obtain the equivalent result,
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}m_{x,\text{out}}}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\Delta V_{x,\text{out}}\rho\right)=\rho\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\Delta A_x\cdot\mathrm{d}x_\text{out}\right)=\rho\Delta A_x\frac{\mathrm{d}x_\text{out}}{\mathrm{d}t}=\rho\Delta A \,u_\text{out}$$

If we define the influx boundary velocity as $u(x)$, then since the width of the control volume is $\Delta x$, the outflux boundary velocity must be $u(x+\Delta x)$.

Comment: How do we deal with having something like $\frac{\partial dx}{\partial t}$ ? Could we expand it as follows?  $\frac{dx_{out}}{dt} = \frac{ d(x + dx)}{dt } = \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{d(dx)}{dt} = u(x) + u(dx) = u(x+dx) $

Comment: I don't know how you'd get a $\partial_t\mathrm{d}x$ term, but I imagine that $\mathrm{d}x$ being infinitesimal would result in a 0 value. It is probably better to think of $\mathrm{d}x_\text{out}/\mathrm{d}t$ as the value of $\mathrm{d}x/\mathrm{d}t$ *evaluated* at out: $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}\vert_{x=\text{out}}$.

Comment: I tried to expand $x_{out} = x + \Delta x $, then tried to take the time derivative of that see if i could arrive to $u(x + dx)$. Really appreciate the explanations, things are making more sense now !